# functionality of protein based on amino acid covalently linked to something

Tags: protein-interaction

This question is directly taken off from "challenge question" as part of my bio-engineering class.

The functionality of any individual protein covalently linked to a device is dependent on the specific amino acid through which it is chemically linked to the device.

Is this a true statement? I believe that different amino acid has different chemistry and orientation so it would affect the functionality but is it enough to say dependent on them. Also could you please provide an example if possible? I cannot think of an example. I would really appreciate your insight as well.

Comment: The if the protein is linked with a residue in the active site, for example, function would definitely be affected.

Comment: Your challenge question was meant to challenge *you* for a reason; your instructor wants you to reason it out. You should not rob yourself of the experience.